# Can't load from documents folder into webView on iOS

Tags: html, ios, webview, document

I'm unsuccessfully trying to load some html and images from documents folder on iOS. Can someone help me to understand why this code does not work?

```
    let html = "<html><body><font size='20>oi</font></body></html>"
    let saveHTML = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("sample.html")
    try? html.data(using: .utf8)!.write(to: saveHTML)
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: saveHTML))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple to solve, it was a lack of rights:

```
webView.loadFileURL(saveHTML, allowingReadAccessTo: saveHTML)
```